# How to 301 redirect from map

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I made a website where I made an English version as well. The English version map is in `/en`.

The normal site of mine, redirects with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The English version is in the `/en` map so I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.nl/en$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does someone know how to 301 redirect when the site is in a folder?

Comment: Of course that 2nd condition doesn’t work, `www.mysite.nl/en` is not a host name. But you can easily match the `en/` prefix in your RewriteRule pattern.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for putting en in uris.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mysite.nl/en/$1 [R=301,L]

##Other rules for redirection.     
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @AmstelStudent, could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you?